# How to programmatically setup StickyHeader in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, header, sticky

I am trying to implement a sticky header feature such as the one seen on twitters profile.  I have setup up my scroll view according and I have been trying to research how to do so, however, I can only find ways that use storyboards.My code will be below.

```
class EditProfileVC: UIViewController {
var imageView: UIImageView!
var image = UIImage(named: "work")


lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentSize.height = 800
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    setupScrollView()
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        setupProfileImageView()

}

func setupScrollView(){

    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 200).isActive=true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    let firstLabel = UILabel()
    firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstLabel.textColor = .white
    firstLabel.text = "Top of our ScrollView"

    scrollView.addSubview(firstLabel)

    firstLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    firstLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    firstLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

Can someone please tell me what I am leaving out and possibly help me construct the header? If the Sticky Header is to complex, A simple header in the UIScrollView will help out a lot. Thank you in advance, 
John 
        [image: Twitter profile sticky header]
[image: twitter profile sticky header]

Comment: Twitter's Header looks like is just a formatted `NavigationBar`

Comment: @SirCJ I’m talking about the profile view. Where it is a select an image

Comment: Do you mean where your profile image and name are at the top and as you scroll they shrink and then the name goes into the navigation bar at the top?  If not perhaps show an image of what you mean.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I edited my answer could you take a look at it for me?

Comment: @SirCJ I posted pictures in my question. Could you please let me know?

Comment: Basically you don't want to make the `UIImageView` (or any header) a sub view of the `UIScrollView` but both are sub views of the same view.  Then you pin the image view to the top of the scroll view and set the top content inset to be the height of the scroll view.  Then use the delegate methods of a `UIScrollView` to update the height of the image view based on the content offset of the scroll view.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I have been researching this for a few days now, and the only way that I have found to implement a sticky header is to use a table view, or a scroll view. In my app, I’m using a scroll view. When I have found ways to use the sticky header in scroll view, they all have been with storyboards. I was just wondering if there is a way to do the same, but programmatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work (it does for me anyway):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Image"))
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        return imageView
    }()

    var imageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1200, height: 1200)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = .green
        self.scrollView.addSubview(testView)
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
        testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)
        self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

        self.imageHeightConstraint = self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        self.imageHeightConstraint.isActive = true

        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let y = 100 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 100)
        let height = max(y, 100)
        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = height
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works thank you! Now all I have to figure out is to show more of the picture! (This method pins my photo all the way to the top and shows about 2 pixels. If I scroll down it shows more!) thank you so much!

Comment: let y = 100 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 100)

is the same as

let y = -scrollView.contentOffset.y

Comment: Yes it is but it shows the working out just in case that helps when answering the question.  Sometimes the working out can be as important as the answer in helping someone build understanding hence why school work often asks to show it.  Does it hurt anything? No, Does it make the answer any less valid? No